# Windows Media Foundation error when calling SetCurrentMediaType

Tags: ms-media-foundation

I am trying to run the github repo https://github.com/sipsorcery/mediafoundationsamples/tree/master/MFWebCamToFile but I get the error **Failed to set media type on source reader. Error: C00D36B4.**. I have no clue what this error is. Can someone help? thanks

Comment: It means that the configuration of the `MediaEncodingProfile` is invalid (perhaps there are hardware issues).